пропущена "}" CS1513
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Class 
{
    public class Inf : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "GameParams", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/GameParams", order = 1)]
        public class GameParams : ScriptableObject { }
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        void Start()
        { 
            ...
        }//2


         
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {

        }
    }//1
}

когда я пишу в метод Start любую вещь, все работает, но если я создаю класс, то "}" под цифрой 2, начинает принадлежать классу INF, а "}" 1, неймспейсу а последняя скобка просто вызывает ошибку

но если я создаю класс - расшифруйте, приведите воспроизводимый пример

любой класс, просто даже если обозначить class a {} в методе Start то будет та же ошибка

Общий совет, пока не разобрались с C# - избегайте вложенности классов, то есть когда класс в классе или метод в методе это нехорошо, может в будущем добавить путаницы.

Внутри метода нельзя определить класс. Это можно сделать только внутри пространства имён или внутри класса, в вопросе - это на уровне public class Inf : MonoBehaviour или public class GameParams : ScriptableObject { }, ну, или внутри GameParams.
